# beforeresize and resizedrag is not getting called extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

```
EastGadgets = Ext.define(null, {
  'extend': 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  'id': 'Id',
  'listeners': {
    resize: function (portal, width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight, eOpts) {
      console.log('hi4');
    },
    resizedrag: function (portal, width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight, eOpt) {
      console.log('hi2');
    },
    beforeresize: function (portal, width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight, eOpt) {
      console.log('hi3');
    }
  }
```

only resize is getting called, beforerisize and resizedrag is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Docs - `Ext.panel.Panel` does not have such events directly. You should add `Ext.resizer.Resizer` component to your `Panel` and set these events handlers to it.

Comment: Actually, I have made my panel resizable, now I want to track the resize start and resize end, so what is the best method to do that?

Comment: You should set listeners to `Ext.resizer.Resizer` component. Have you added this component to the Panel?

Comment: Actually, my ext object at much later stage, so I cannot add Ext.resizer.Resizer component to my Panel as I won't be able to get 'elToResize' as of now. Correct me if I am wrong as I am very new to this framework.

Comment: There is a `target` property when creating the Resizer, which you can point to your Panel's element: `(your_panel.el)`.

Comment: Since, my component is yet to be rendered, it gives me the error that can't read el of undefined

Comment: So add Resizer within `render` listener of the Panel.